# Inject HTML in Angular (>1.2) with input tags and other "unsafe" elements

Tags: angularjs

I have some HTML I get in JSON which needs to be injected into a page.  I used `$sce.trustAsHtml` and bound the output with `ngBindHtml`, but that strips out, apparently, tags like `<select>` and `<input>` which are "unsafe."  Is there some way to tell Angular I really, actually did intend to insert exactly the HTML I asked for into the page?

Right now I just have something like `$scope.$watch('response.htmlBody', function(){$('#container').html($scope.response.htmlBody);}` and it seems to work as intended but that seems like a pretty lousy hack.

In this case the HTML is free of Angular-specific elements, so I do not need to worry about compiling it again.

Comment: Works fine for `<select>` and `<input>` - http://plnkr.co/edit/4hEtkQywjoSwoKq6y9kq?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev Well now I'm really puzzled.  It stripped them all out for me (although it left the plain text for select menu options) and when I went searching around I read an answer somewhere on SO suggesting that was actually the intended behavior.

Comment: Can you create a plunker reproducing your observed behavior?

Comment: @NewDev Well, your sample is the desired behavior; I don't understand why I'm getting something different.

Answer (score 1):

`$sce.trustAsHtml` and `ng-bind-html` should work without removing `<input>` and `<select>`:

```
$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);

<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4hEtkQywjoSwoKq6y9kq?p=preview)

Comment: While I appreciate that you don't have all the information to debug my environment or whatever is causing my problem, I can't really accept an answer that tells me to do exactly what I said I tried in the question.

Comment: That's fine. "Accepted answer" means it solved your problem as it was stated. If it didn't, then it didn't.